# adding a before event to either an IDictionary or class

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, idictionary

Is it possible to create an event before an item is added or updated to an IDictionary?

```
public static IDictionary<string, Aircraft> aircraftList = new Dictionary<string, Aircraft>();
```

and I use it like this

```
MainForm.aircraftList[acNumber].FlightStatus = strFlying;
```

What I want to do is not to update the value if the new value is null, empty string or an int == 0

Aircraft is a class with lots of values which are a mix of strings int's and doubles...

or is there a way of doing this type of action within the class?

currently I'm doing this everywhere I assign a value via an if statement, I assume there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could roll out your own `Dictionary` class and use custom `Add()` function (and other functions). Something like this:

```
class MyCustomDictionary : Dictionary<string, Aircraft>
{
  public new Add(string key, Aircraft value)
  {
    if (YOUR_CONDITION)
    {
      base.Add(key, value);
    }
  }
}
```

You should note the use of `new` keyword here. The `Add()` function cannot be overridden because the base class doesn't define it as `overridable`. So you must use `new` in your definition.

Comment: thank you I instated it thus:         public static MyCustomDictionary aircraftList = new MyCustomDictionary();    .    However it never seems to raise the event. i have set a break point on the if condition.

Comment: @Adrian: It won't raise any events. It will just allow you to place your condition in one central place, which will be checked before actually adding the item to the dictionary.

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding, sorry if so, but the condition never hits the breakpoint I put a console.WriteLine before it too, but it is never executed!

Comment: @Adrian: Must be something in your implementation. Do you see multiple overloads of the `Add()` function from where u call it?

Comment: Consider using an ObservableCollection

Comment: @HeinzKessler: What for?

Answer (score 0):

I have to be honest with you, I'm a bit confused as to what you are requesting... However, I've noticed a couple of issues with your example code which could be causing the problem you're experiencing?

First off, **IDictionary** is a collection object interface, and yet you are treating it as an array, which to me is a tad suspicious.

Secondly, **Aircraft** is a class and yet you are not initialising it when setting a value to FlightStatus.

So what you should be doing is either:

```
aircraftList.Add(strKey, new Aircraft() {FlightStatus = strFlying});
```

or

```
Aircraft ac = new Aircraft();

// set the ac values
ac.FlightStatus = strFlying;

aircraftList.Add(strKey, ac);
```

You can add conditional statement before adding the object to the dictionary.

Finally, what do you mean when asking about *adding a before event*? If you follow dotNET's example you could add your own OnBeforeEvent method/Invoke() within Add() method declaration.